# Python input=output loop

Tags: python, math, loops

I am trying to make a python loop where the output is used as the input, until the output and input is equivalent, this is the statement that i am trying to solve:

```
  1
----- = x 
 1+x
```

The result will be 1 less than the golden ratio (0.618034...), i have done it on paper and it takes about 20 loops for a few decimal places of accuracy.  Please tell me what type of python loop i would use to to solve this?

Comment: A `while` loop.

Comment: @shashwat -- That's **exactly** the comment I was about to post ...

Comment: I will not ask better questions if i don't know what is wrong with them.  please explain the downvote and give constructive criticism.

Comment: The bit that's wrong is that you haven't tried anything. There's all of **two** ways to loop in Python.

Comment: @kylek Constructive criticism: show some effort. It's great that you have started by working the problem by hand. Now what have you done as far as code? Do you know the kinds of loops that Python has? If not, google will help you there. If you do, what have you tried in code?

Comment: Thanks for telling me how i can improve.

Comment: It's okay to be completely lost at first when trying to wrap your head around a concept--in fact, it's pretty normal when you're first learning. But you should always provide information on what your thought process is, why you are confused, and what you have already tried, preferably with examples. This not only makes it easier for responders to help you, but also shows that you are putting in your fair share of effort, and not just expecting them to do the work for you! and if you don't have answers to those questions, that would be your cue to do a little more research before posting.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I should of provided examples of what i have tried, i did not want someone to do the work for me as i said in the posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, based on what you're describing here, you want a while loop, since you want to keep doing something until a given condition becomes true.

```
lastOutput = 0; # an arbitrary starting value: the last output value 
                # needs to be shared between loop cycles, so its 
                # scope must be outside the while loop

startingValue = # whatever you start at for input
finished = False # flag for tracking whether desired value has been reached
while (!finished):
    # body of loop:
    # here, you need to take lastOutput, run it through the 
    # function again, and check if the new output value is the
    # same as the input that created it. If so, you are done,
    # so set the flag to True, and note that the correct value is now stored in lastOutput
    # If not, set the new output as lastOutput, and go again!

# ...and now finish up with whatever you want to do now that you've 
# found the value (print it, etc.)!
```

As far as the logic for checking whether the values are the same, you will need to have some sort of threshold value for precision purposes (otherwise it'll run forever!), and I would recommend writing that check in its own method for modularity's sake.

Hope this helps, and just let me know if you need me to post more actual code (I tried not to give away too much actual code).

Comment: I was going to use the rounding function as the threshold value.